# Custom view multiple-value field

Tags: views, 8, theming

What do I need to adjust to make this code work?

```
{% if fields.field_video_video[1].content|striptags|trim is not empty %}    
  {{ fields.field_video_video.content }}
{% endif %}
```

The logic is to check if this field (a URL field) has more than a value; if it has more than a value, print the content, starting from [1].